# Relationship between circles and polynomials

Tags: geometry, analysis

Taylor's theorem implies that a sequence of polynomials converges on a circle. Does this imply there is some nontrivial relationship between circles and polynomials?

Comment: are you talking about radius of convergence for a power series?

Comment: yes, that is correct